# How to clear elements in a List<> which are similar to each other in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a list but in this list there are lots of elements which have the same value. I want to clear values which have same value and have one of each element group.

Comment: Do you ever want to be able to store more than one in the list, also do you care about the order the list will be in when you do a foreach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using 3.5+ you can use Linq to accomplish that:

```
myDistinctList = myList.Distinct();
```

This assumes that the list value is a primitive or an object that implements IComparable.

Comment: Thank you that was the exact solution

Comment: I thought OP was trying to merge two lists and eliminate the duplicates.

Comment: but it is going to distinct for what?Think of I have three diffrent columned datarow list.And i want to use distinct method for ID column??

Comment: Now I'm not sure. I read the question again, and it sounds like OP is asking to filter one list. Can you clarify @Aykut?

Comment: Yes i want to filter a list that have the same values.Ex :
{1,1,1,1,2,2,2,4,4,4,4}.
I want this list as 
{1,2,4}

Comment: but assume that list consist of datarows.and distinc them for ID column

Comment: @Aykut: If you have a complex class, it'll have to implement the IComparer interface in order to function properly. But in the case of a datarow, if they are the same id and don't have the same fields then the id isn't truly distinct. In your case that you mentioned, the primitives should use the distinct extension.

Answer (score 1):

you could put them into a set, which enforces uniqueness, as long as you have #equals declared for correct comparison.

Comment: As an aside, Linq `Distinct` is internally implemented as a `Set` (`internal` framework utility class similar to a `HashSet`), so it also has these requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In C# 4.0 use Distinct extension method:

```
var values=new List<Type>;
var result=result.Distict().ToList();
return result;
```

**Update:**
if your type is reference type use:

```
result.Distict(IEqualityComparer<Type>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [linq](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) :

- Remove duplicate : .Distinct()
- Group : .GroupBy()

Answer (score 0):

**If you're trying to merge two lists**

You can use `Union`.

```
List<int> results = lst1.Union(lst2).ToList();
```

You could also use `Concat` and `Distinct` to accomplish this:

```
List<int> lst3 = lst1.Concat(lst2).Distinct().ToList();
```

**If you're trying to remove duplicates from one list of objects**

You can use `Distinct` with an `IEqualityComparer<>`.

```
List<DataRow> results = lst1.Distinct(new RowComparer()).ToList();

public class RowComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
    public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y) {
        return x.Field<int>("ID") == y.Field<int>("ID");
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj) {
        return obj.Field<int>("ID").GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

**If you're trying to merge multiple lists of objects and remove duplicates**

You can use `Union` with an `IEqualityComparer<>`.

```
List<DataRow> results = lst1.Union(lst2, new RowComparer()).ToList();

public class RowComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
    public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y) {
        return x.Field<int>("ID") == y.Field<int>("ID");
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj) {
        return obj.Field<int>("ID").GetHashCode();
    }
}
```